# Why I cant read last string from file?

Tags: c++

I can read all string besides last "Yury Chen  88     3939202"

```
  ifstream file("text.txt");
  string s;
  int counter = 0;
  for(file >> s; !file.eof(); file >> s)
  {
    if (counter<=3){
      templist.push_back(s);
      counter +=1;
    }
    else{
      list.push_back(templist);
      counter = 0;
      templist.clear();
      templist.push_back(s);
      counter +=1;
    }
}
```

text.txt is

```
John        Jones        12  5412354
Kevin   Abatsa 23   6431264
Name    Surname      31    1239523
Yury Chen  88     3939202
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably with:

```
for(file >> s; !file.eof(); file >> s)
```

When this streams the last string in the file - `3939202` - it's proabbly setting the `eof` flag, so you exit without processing that string.  (We can't say for sure because we can't see if there's whitespace after `3939202` in your file...).

Just change to:

```
while (file >> s)
```